# Windows 8 and wpf printing

Tags: wpf, windows-8

I use print visual in windows 7 and wpf and printing seems fine. I get small spool files.
Under Windows 8 they become images several MB! Any idea what might get them treated as images??

Comment: Maybe it's somehow related to a printer you're using?

Comment: i just use .printVisual(usercontrol,"title");

Comment: You didn't answer Filip's question. PrintVisual is probably going to whatever is the default printer so is the printer the same as the one you printed to from Win 7?